# Rails; 1:1 relation in polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I rarely see polymorphic design in `has_one` relation in db schema.

I simply would love to achieve `1:1` relation between `invoice_item` to others(`subscripiton_item` or `usage_item`).

I know polymorphic relation is not good design.

How could I achieve 1:1 relations without polymorphic?

**Should I make make a FK either also the PK (which guarantees uniqueness) or put a unique constraint on it?**

```
SubscriptionItems
--------
- id
- title
- period_start
- period_end

UsageItems
--------
- id
- title
- description


InvoiceItems
--------
- id
- itemable_id
- itemable_type (either a subscription_item *or* a usage_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

SubscriptionItem

```
    #model subscription_item.rb
    ---
    has_one  :invoice_item
    ---
```

UsageItem

```
    #model usage_item.rb
    ---
    has_one  :invoice_item
    ---
```

InvoiceItems

```
    #model invoice_item.rb
    ---
    belongs_to :usage_item, :class_name => 'UsageItem', :foreign_key => 'usage_item_id'
    belongs_to :subscription_item, :class_name => 'SubscriptionItem', :foreign_key => 'subscription_item_id'
    ---
```

Comment: I'd love to make sure that invoice_item belongs to either usage_item or subscription_item.